# Pushing into array not working inside jQuery function

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular2-materialize

I'm using [MaterializeCSS's autocomplete](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) with [Angular2-Materialize](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize), and I'm trying to push the selected value into an array. However, I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Here's my component:

```
public items: any[] = [];

addItem() {
  $('.autocomplete-content').on('click', 'li', function () {
    let value = $(this).text().trim();
    this.items.push({ [value]: true });
  });
}
```

If I try to `push` some random thing outside the `jQuery` function, it works.

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="text" (change)="addItem()" materialize="autocomplete" [materializeParams]="[{'data': myData | async}]">
```

Comment: is that javascript? I'll admit I'm not up to date on my ES6

Comment: It's Angular2 with Typescript.

Comment: might wanna tag it typescript then

Comment: I notice that you are using `this` twice within that function, but seemingly expecting it to be the clicked element the first time (which it is) and then some other object the second time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in your function refers to the clicked element, not your class' scope. So either use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
 $('.autocomplete-content').on('click', 'li', ev => {
    let value = $(ev.target).text().trim();
    this.items.push({ [value]: true });
  });
```

Or `bind(this)` to make the class' this available in the `click` handler

```
 $('.autocomplete-content').on('click', 'li', function (ev) {
    let value = $(ev.target).text().trim();
    this.items.push({ [value]: true });
  }.bind(this));
```

Note to change `$(this)` to the element you can pass to the function.

You could also define something like `that` in `addItem()` and use that instead...

```
addItem() {
  var that = this;  
  $('.autocomplete-content').on('click', 'li', function () {
    let value = $(this).text().trim();
    that.items.push({ [value]: true });
  });
}
```

Comment: But won't that break `$(this).text()`?

Comment: The first argument of the event handler is the `event` object, not the element. But you can use `event.target`

Comment: It's duplicating data when I'm pushing. E.g. for the first selected tag, it pushes once. But when I select another one, it pushes that value twice. Do you have any idea why?